# How to use bmkp-new-bookmark-default-names in bookmark+?

Tags: customize, bookmarks

I am using [`bookmark+.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus) in Emacs 25.1. When I press `C-x r m` (bound to `bookmark-set`) and point is on a symbol, it will be used as the default candidate for the new bookmark to be created.

I would like to change this behavior slightly, such the the current line number (as given by `line-number-at-pos`) is appended to the name. So for example if point is on a symbol `my-test-function` at line 31 in a buffer `my-lisp-functions.el` and I press `C-x r m` the default candidate should be `my-test-function:31` (and not just `my-test-function` as is the current behavior).

After browsing the file [`bookmark+-1.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/bookmark%2B-1.el), I think I have to customize the variable `bmkp-new-bookmark-default-names`. I would like to do this from lisp code (i.e. not use the `M-x customize` gui).

The documentation of the variable `bmkp-new-bookmark-default-names` says:

> The option value is a list of functions that do not require an
>   argument and return a string (or nil).  They are invoked, in order, to
>   produce the default names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use something like this as one of the functions:

```el
(defun foo ()
  (let* ((ff    (function-called-at-point))
         (ff    (and ff  (symbolp ff)  (symbol-name ff)))
         (line  (format "%d" (line-number-at-pos))))
    (if ff (concat ff ":" line) line))
```

(Could just use that as an anonymous function - don't need to name it.)

Example with only one function (that one) -- put this in your init file:

```el
(setq bmkp-new-bookmark-default-names  (list 'foo))
```

If you *do* use Customize then just click `INS` and add `foo` (if defined) or the equivalent lambda expression; then save.

(See also [Autonamed Bookmarks](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus#AutonamedBookmarks) for examples of providing names for autonamed bookmarks, in case that is really what you want.)